# How Do I exclude a Magento category from the main menu

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-community, css

How Do I exclude a Magento category from the main menu and still maintain it in the side bar. I have tried these two code I got while searching on Google by replacing the default magento to these but its not working

Here is the code

```
<?php $_menu = "" ?>
  <?php if($_menu): ?>
  <div class="nav-container">
  <ul id="nav">
  <?php foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>
  <?php if(stristr('71,70,69', $_category->getId()) === FALSE) : ?> 
  <?php echo $this->drawItem($_category) ?>
  <?php endif ?>
   <?php endforeach ?>

   <?php // echo $_menu ?>
    </ul>
   </div>
  <?php endif  ?>
```

And here is the second piece of code. Also I got this from googling.

```
 <?php $_menu = ''?>
  <?php foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>
  <?php $_menu .= $this->drawItem($_category) ?>
 <?php endforeach ?>
 <?php if ($_menu): ?>
   <div class="nav-container">
      <ul id="nav">
    <?php foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>
       <?php if (!in_array($_category->getId(), array(12,34,56))) : ?> <?php echo $this-     >drawItem($_category) ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
     <?php endforeach ?>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

None of them seem to be working. I am using magento 1. 7.1

Thanks for your help

Comment: By "sidebar" do you mean the "Shop By" block of anchor categories?

Comment: No I have a side bar menu listing all categories

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try the "Include in Navigation Menu" option near the bottom of "Manage Categories" page in admin.  It might not affect your sidebar as it does not affect all block types which list categories.

Comment: This should be up more, don't want people to think that it's only possible by altering code. A sidebar that's well written should support this (or atleast have its own option)

Answer (score -1):

First Make sure that your category ids `69,70,71` is exist or not.if it is correct then do the second method you have tried as,
`if(in_array($_category->getId(),array(69,70,71)==false):`or simply`if(!in_array($_category->getId(),array(69,70,71)):`. It should work.

Comment: When I use the second code with your recommendation I get a blank menu. No menu displays.